# Why am I getting a false value at if (users.contains(user))?

Tags: java, authentication, java.util.scanner, logical-operators, login-control

I think the user.contains is not reading every line and is only checking the first line.  I had this working right earlier(I am testing the duplicate user portion of my code), but now my program is skipping :

```
{    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate user found."); 
            goahead=false;
            dispose();
            }
```

I am not sure what I did, or how I managed to break my own program. Now its skipping all the way to:

```
else { if (hs.contains(new String(un+" "+pw))) { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User, Found Access Granted!");
                    dispose();
                }
```

Where did I go wrong?

```
private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String un = UserName.getText().trim();
        String pw = Password.getText().trim();
        HashSet hs= new HashSet();
        HashSet users = new HashSet(); 
        boolean goahead=true; 
        try {
            Scanner Scan = new Scanner(new File("Login.txt"));
            while (Scan.hasNextLine()) { 
                String authenticator = Scan.nextLine().trim();
                String[] autparts=authenticator.split(" "); 
                String user = autparts[0].trim();
                if (goahead){
                    if (users.contains(user)) {
                        if (user.equals(un)) {    
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate user found."); 
                            goahead=false;
                            dispose();
                        }
                    } else {
                        hs.add(authenticator);
                        users.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        if (goahead) {
            if (createAccount.isSelected() & (hs.contains(new String(un+" "+pw)))){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Already Exsist! No Need to create a new account. ");
                dispose();
            } else { 
                if (hs.contains(new String(un+" "+pw))) { 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User, Found Access Granted!");
                    dispose();
                }  else { 
                    if (createAccount.isSelected()){
                        try {
                            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Login.txt", true)));

                            output.println(un+" "+pw);
                            output.close(); 
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.out.printf("error %s/n", ex );
                        }   
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome!"+" " + un+" "+"Please Relogin Now");
                        dispose();
                    }else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user doesn't exist or password incorrect. "); 
                        dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

the following is my output and whats in the txt file. :[image: screen shot of the debug results and txt file]

Comment: Please format code correctly.

Comment: `users` has size `0` in your posted debugger window.

Comment: `if (goahead) {` is always `true`, so `if (users.contains(user)) {` is actually never evaluated...

Comment: Thank you, these answers do make sense. I am not sure how to fix it. ( I am new )

Comment: You're chasing your tail, you're trying to load the file and populate the `users` `Set` WHILE trying to ascertain if the value the user has provided is within the list...??  Either populate the `Set` AND THEN check if the input exists OR check to see if the user exists by reading the file...

Comment: I figured out the solution. When I was entering the passwords for my program I was hitting the  tab key instead of hitting the space key, which was creating an extra set of spaces. once I eliminated those everything worked as it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

I have formatted your code now:

```
String un = UserName.getText().trim();
if (goahead){
       if (users.contains(user)) 
       {
         if (user.equals(un)) 
         {    
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate user found."); 
             goahead=false;
             dispose();
         }
       } 
       else 
       {
        hs.add(authenticator);
        users.add(user);
       }
}
```

Now when the flag `goahead` is set to `false` dont we need to reset it to `true` somewhere? If HashSet contains user then why do you need to again compare name of user? You should have defined `equals` for the user itself. Nope?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to chasing your tail, doing two things at one, reading the file/populating the `Set` AND checking for duplicates.  Instead, do one at a time...

Something like...

```
    // You could pre-load these and cache the result instead
    // of reading it each time, but that's up to you
    Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>(25);
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Login.txt"))) {

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String value = scan.nextLine();
            String[] parts = value.split(" ");
            credentials.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }

    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Make your required checks here
    if (credentials.containsKey(un)) {
        if (credentials.get(un).equals(pw)) {
            // Validated
        } else {
            // Wrong password
        }
    } else {
        // New user...?
    }
```

Comment: Agree. Doing so many things at a time causes confusion to others as well. It is difficult to understand the intention.

Comment: @akhil_mittal I'm still trying to figure out what the code is "suppose" to do, but that's my best guess :P

Comment: I will toy with this and see what I can come up with. Thank you

Comment: @CAPTiNDANCE Please make sure you spend some time in formatting the code as well. It will help you only in getting good solution faster :)

Comment: @akhil_mittal I will format this better. I am still at a stage of figuring out how to write code, though I want to be good at this. thank you everyone for your help.